# Android Twitter Oauth get screen name

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

i want to know my screen name after logged in to twitter using oauth in android.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void Authorize()
    {
        try {
            Consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
            StrictMode.enableDefaults();
            String authUrl = Provider.retrieveRequestToken(Consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try
        {           
            Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();  
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
                String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                Consumer.setTokenWithSecret(Consumer.getToken(),Consumer.getTokenSecret());
                Provider.retrieveAccessToken(Consumer, oauth_verifier);
                HttpParameters params1 = Provider.getResponseParameters();
                String userName = params1.getFirst("screen_name");
                Toast.makeText(this, "user name >>>>>>>>" + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Throw ex onResume function but e.getMessage() is null
 ( **Provider.retrieveAccessToken(Consumer, oauth_verifier);** error line )

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you please provide code for CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer or jar if any?

Answer (score 1):

You should do params1.get("screen_name").getFirst();

like this

```
SortedSet<String> screenNameSet = mProvider.getResponseParameters().get("screen_name");  
String screenName = screenNameSet.first();
```